# How can you use dynamic props with @keyframes using makeStyles from react material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, css-animations, keyframe

I want to dynamically generate a `@keyframes` animation using the `makeStyles` helper from react mui. I want to access props to generate this css keyframes. However, it does not seem to work.

What I have tried - simplified example ([Link to CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-surf-vn325?file=/src/App.js)):

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  h1: {
    animation: "$works 1s infinite"
  },
  h2: {
    animation: "$failsWithProps 1s infinite"
  },
  h3: {
    animation: "$workAround 1s infinite"
  },
  h4: {
    animation: "$workAroundFailsWithProps 1s infinite"
  },
  [`@keyframes works`]: {
    from: { opacity: 1 },
    to: { opacity: 0 }
  },
  [`@keyframes failsWithProps`]: props => ({
    from: { opacity: props.opacity },
    to: { opacity: 0 }
  }),
  [`@keyframes workAround`]: {
    ...workAround(0.9)
  },
  [`@keyframes workAroundFailsWithProps`]: props => ({
    ...workAroundFailsWithProps(props)
  })
});

function workAround(opacity) {
  return {
    from: { opacity },
    to: { opacity: 0 }
  };
}

function workAroundFailsWithProps(props) {
  return {
    from: { opacity: props.opacity },
    to: { opacity: 0 }
  };
}

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles({ opacity: 0.9 });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={classes.h1}>works</h1>
      <h2 className={classes.h2}>failsWithProps</h2>
      <h3 className={classes.h3}>workAround</h3>
      <h4 className={classes.h4}>workAroundFailsWithProps</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: [Created an issue on Github repository](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/21011)